# Crash should not show any error

Tags: android, runtime-error

In Android, runtime error dialog is prompted when error occurs. Is it possible to hide it? Or just hide it in production mode? Since it is showing some error message about the app which should not be exposed to users.

Comment: No, it is not possible. In general, fiddling with the standard behaviour of the system/UI/etc. is considered bad practice and in many cases a consistent behaviour is enforced by the OS (Personally, for example, I would hate a "silently crashing" application...)

Comment: If you enclose the error prone pieces of your code into try-catch blocks consciously, then your app will never show this kind of error dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid your app to reaching the force close, when your app ends up in force close so your main thread has been killed and your app is no longer running and it's not accessible in coding so you can make another thread and handle situation and show custom dialog to the user.

Maybe [Acra](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) in Github would help you handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom handler for uncaught exceptions using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(..)` on your main thread. There you can do what you need to do, including calling the default behaviour if you use the following pattern:

```
public class ExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * The default handler.
     */
    private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

    /**
     * Constructs the instance and sets the default handler to the one currently
     * active at the time of construction.
     */
    public ExceptionHandler() 
    {
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
    {
        // do your stuff            

        // if you want to resume with the default behaviour, you call this
        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }
}
```

In your `Activity`/`Application`:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
```